# Firebase response depending on Firestore Query does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Depending on whether there is an entry in Cloud Firestore with the correct DocumentId. However, this does not work because my function sends the status 200 before even finishing the query. So how can I get that working?

Here is my code:

```
access = false;

admin.firebase().collection("tuere").doc(door).collection("eintritt").get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if(doc.id === uid){
            access = true;
            console.log("May open door " + uid);
        }
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

res.status(200).send(access);
```

When I open the Tab in Chrome and let it load "false" appears, but when I wait like 15 Seconds "May open door (uid)" appears in the Logs.
How can I solve this problem and how can i get my function to run faster?

Answer (score 1):

You should send the HTTP response when the promise resolves, so within the then of the query promise: like that:

```
access = false;

admin.firebase().collection("tuere").doc(door).collection("eintritt").get()
.then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if(doc.id === uid){
            access = true;
            console.log("May open door " + uid);
        }
    });
    res.status(200).send(access);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
});
```

Also, you should send an HTTP response in case of error, this is why I added `res.status(500).send(err);` in the catch

I would suggest you look this video from Doug Stevenson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

---

Also there is a point which surprises me: shouln't you use

```
admin.firestore().collection("tuere").doc(door)....
```

instead of

```
admin.firebase().collection("tuere").doc(door)
```

I have to look in the reference, but I have the feeling that admin.firebase() does not exist.